# Bing Image Search API request using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, search, bing

I'm attempting to use the Bing image search API according to [this article](http://microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn760784.aspx).

I need to make an ajax request to https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/images/search

Attached is an image of the test code I've written to attempt to get this to work. The app.js file is linked to an html file that has a button on it.

[Screenshot of code on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/no6vR.png)

I then receive the error `app.js:7 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -`

I believe my ajax syntax is off. Could someone help me set this request up properly?

Answer (score 0):

Huzzah!

A friend helped me out! Ill uploaded to the revised code that got me to the success part of the request.

[resolved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjzaU.png)